# How to create Barcode on PDF in Magento 2.3.x

Tags: magento, zend-framework, magento2, barcode, magento-2.3

I am trying to create Barcode in PDF file in Magento 2.3.x Version,

Below code was working in Magento 2.1.8

However this is throwing below error -

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   Zend\Barcode\Renderer\Pdf::setResource() must be an instance of
>   ZendPdf\PdfDocument, instance of Zend\Barcode\Renderer\Pdf given,
>   called in /var/www/magento/app/code/MyCompany/Ups/Helper/Custom.php on
>   line 81

```
<?php
namespace Mycompany\Ups\Helper;

use Zend\Barcode\Barcode;
use Zend\Barcode\Renderer;

use Zend\Barcode\Renderer\Pdf;

class Custom extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    protected $_logger;

    protected $_fontPath;

    protected $_pdf;

    public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Module\Dir\Reader $configReader,
        Pdf $pdf
    )
    {
        $this->_logger = $logger;
        $this->_fontPath = $configReader->getModuleDir('etc', 'Mycompany_Ups') . '/lib/fonts/';
        $this->_pdf = $pdf;
    }

    public function getOrderConfirmationPdf($order)
    {
        try {
            $pdf = new \Zend_Pdf();
            $page = new \Zend_Pdf_Page(\Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);

            $color1 = new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.0);   // (float number). 0.0 (black) - 1.0 (white)

            $font = \Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(\Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA_BOLD);
            $page->setFont($font,40);

            $page->setFillColor($color1)->drawText('ORDER CONFIRMATION', 60, 720);

            $font = \Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(\Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA);
            $page->setFont($font,30.5);
            $page->setFillColor($color1)->drawText('THIS IS NOT A SHIPPING LABEL', 60, 620);

            $page->setFont($font,16.5);
            $page->setFillColor($color1)->drawText('PLACE THIS INSIDE THE SHIPPING CARTON WITH THE', 75, 520);
            $page->setFillColor($color1)->drawText('CONTROL BOARD', 220, 500);
            $page->setFillColor($color1)->drawText('WRITE THE BELOW ORDER CONFIRMATION NUMBER ON', 65, 460);
            $page->setFillColor($color1)->drawText('THE OUTSIDE OF THE SHIPPING CARTON', 125, 440);

            $font = \Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(\Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA_BOLD);
            $page->setFont($font,15);
            $page->setFillColor($color1)->drawText('(Order Confirmation Number: '.$order->getIncrementId().')', 145, 370);


            $font = \Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(\Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA);
            $page->setFont($font,30.5);
            $page->setFillColor($color1)->drawText('THIS IS NOT A SHIPPING LABEL', 60, 100);

            $pdf->pages[] = $page;

/*          \Zend_Barcode::setBarcodeFont($this->_fontPath.'helvetica-normal.ttf');
            $barcodeOptions = array('text' => $order->getIncrementId(),'barHeight' => 100,'factor'=> 2.1,'drawText' => TRUE, 'withChecksum' => TRUE, 'stretchText' => TRUE, 'withChecksumInText' => TRUE, 'barThickWidth' => 2, 'barThinWidth' => 2);
            $rendererOptions = array('topOffset' => 530,'leftOffset' => 185); 
            $pdfWithBarcode = \Zend_Barcode::factory('code128', 'pdf', $barcodeOptions, $rendererOptions)->setResource($pdf,0)->draw();*/

            Barcode::setBarcodeFont($this->_fontPath.'helvetica-normal.ttf');
            $barcodeOptions = array('text' => 'ZEND-FRAMEWORK');
            $rendererOptions = array();
            $renderer = Barcode::factory('code128', 'pdf', $barcodeOptions, $rendererOptions);
            $renderer->setResource($pdf, $page)->draw();

            $pdf_str = $pdf->render();
            //$pdf->save("/var/www/html/magento2/mage2/pub/From_Helper_".$order->getIncrementId().".pdf");
            unset($pdf);
            return $pdf_str;
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            mail("rdambare@test.com","ORDER CONFIRMATION PDF ERROR: ".$order->getIncrementId(),$e->getMessage);
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}
```

I am using this code in Helper in my custom module.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Below is sample of PDF I want to generate.

[image]

Comment: I think you can write Zend_Barcode directly no need to write this symbol '\'

Comment: @Jinesh I tried that way as well. But still not working.

Comment: still getting same error

Comment: Yes.. Can you please correct code if any thing is missing

Comment: Please check my answer

Comment: Still getting same error, PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Zend_Barcode' . Please note I am using Magento 2.3.X version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198472/discussion-between-rahul-and-jinesh).

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
<?php
namespace MyCompany\Ups\Helper;
include_once '/var/www/magento/fpdf181/fpdf.php';
use \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Zend\Config\Config;
use Zend_Barcode;
// use Zend_Barcode;
class Data extends AbstractHelper {
    const LABEL_FOLDER = 'media/sales/order/labels/';
    const FONT_FOLDER = 'media/fonts/';
    protected $_filePointer = NULL;
    protected $_directoryList;
    protected $_logger;
    protected $_fontPath;
    protected $_rootDirectory;
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context, \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $custLogger, \Magento\Framework\Module\Dir\Reader $configReader, \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem, DirectoryList $directoryList) {
        $this->_logger = $custLogger;
        $this->_directoryList = $directoryList;
        $this->_pubPath = $directoryList->getPath('pub');
        $this->_rootDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::ROOT);
        $this->_fontPath = $configReader->getModuleDir('etc', 'MyCompany_Ups') . '/lib/fonts/';
        $this->_storeManager = $context->getStoreManager();
    }
    public function getOrderConfirmationPdf($order) {
        try {
            $pdf = new \Zend_Pdf();
            $page = new \Zend_Pdf_Page(\Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
            $color1 = new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.0); // (float number). 0.0 (black) - 1.0 (white)
            $font = \Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(\Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA_BOLD);
            $page->setFont($font, 40);
            $page->setFillColor($color1)->drawText('ORDER CONFIRMATION', 60, 720);
            $font = \Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(\Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA);
            $page->setFont($font, 30.5);
            $page->setFillColor($color1)->drawText('THIS IS NOT A SHIPPING LABEL', 60, 620);
            $page->setFont($font, 16.5);
            $page->setFillColor($color1)->drawText('PLACE THIS INSIDE THE SHIPPING CARTON WITH THE', 75, 520);
            $page->setFillColor($color1)->drawText('CONTROL BOARD', 220, 500);
            $page->setFillColor($color1)->drawText('WRITE THE BELOW ORDER CONFIRMATION NUMBER ON', 65, 460);
            $page->setFillColor($color1)->drawText('THE OUTSIDE OF THE SHIPPING CARTON', 125, 440);
            $font = \Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(\Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA_BOLD);
            $page->setFont($font, 15);
            $page->setFillColor($color1)->drawText('(Order Confirmation Number: ' . $order->getIncrementId() . ')', 145, 370);
            $font = \Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(\Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA);
            $page->setFont($font, 30.5);
            $page->setFillColor($color1)->drawText('THIS IS NOT A SHIPPING LABEL', 60, 100);
            $pdf->pages[] = $page;


            Zend_Barcode::setBarcodeFont($this->_fontPath . 'helvetica-normal.ttf');
            $barcodeConfig = array('text' => $order->getIncrementId(), 'barHeight' => 100, 'factor' => 2.1, 'drawText' => TRUE, 'withChecksum' => TRUE, 'stretchText' => TRUE, 'withChecksumInText' => TRUE, 'barThickWidth' => 2, 'barThinWidth' => 2);
            $rendererConfig = array('topOffset' => 530, 'leftOffset' => 185);
            $renderer = Zend_Barcode::factory('code128', 'pdf', $barcodeConfig, $rendererConfig)->setResource($pdf, 0);
            $renderer->draw();



            $pdf_str = $pdf->render();
            $pdf->save("/var/www/magento/pub/media/sales/order/labels/From_Helper_" . $order->getIncrementId() . ".pdf");
            unset($pdf);
            return $pdf_str;
        }
        catch(Exception $e) {
            mail("rdambare@test.com", "ORDER CONFIRMATION PDF ERROR: " . $order->getIncrementId(), $e->getMessage);
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

Comment: still getting same error that PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Zend_Barcode' .

Comment: which magento version are you using?

Comment: Magento ver. 2.3.1

Answer (score 0):

Try https://github.com/picqer/php-barcode-generator

Install through composer:

`composer require picqer/php-barcode-generator`

Usage
Initiate the barcode generator for the output you want, then call the ->getBarcode() routine as many times as you want.

`$generator = new Picqer\Barcode\BarcodeGeneratorHTML();
echo $generator->getBarcode('081231723897', $generator::TYPE_CODE_128);`